# django model function in template Could not parse the remainder: '()'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model function that looks like:

```
def follow_up_date(self):
        return self.date_worked+timedelta(days=self.follow_up_days)
```

I am trying to render the result of this function for each instantiation of the model I loop over in my template:

```
                                                   {% for claim in claims %}
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td>${{claim.due}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{claim.follow_up_date()}}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    {% endfor %}
```

I get the error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'claim.follow_up_date()'

I could have sworn I've done this before.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to just leave off the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `claim.follow_up_date()` as function, just use `claim.follow_up_date` in your django template and it will work. i.e.

```
{% for claim in claims %}
<tr>
    <td>${{claim.due}}</td>
    <td>{{claim.follow_up_date}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the python's [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) decorator:

```
@property
def follow_up_date(self):
    return self.date_worked+timedelta(days=self.follow_up_days)
```

And the in your template:

```
...
<td>{{claim.follow_up_date}}</td>
...
```